# C# Optimize HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm making my own HTTPWebRequest class and I'm trying to optimize the time it takes to read the buffer and make a request, so far it takes around **800-1000ms** for every request to google.com

Same code in C++ takes ~ **200ms** any suggestions how I could optimize this better?

```
public class OWebReq
{
public string LastError;
public bool LastOK = false;
public OWebReq()
{

}
public static void Init()
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = (WebProxy)null;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
}
public string GET(string url, WebProxy proxy = null)
{
    LastOK = false;
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36";
    req.Proxy = proxy;
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.Timeout = 5000;
    req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    try
    {
        using(var response=(HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if(responseStream!=null)
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    return sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LastError = ex.Message;
        return null;
    }
     return null;
 }
}
```

Executing code till `var response=(HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()` takes ~ **350ms**

Comment: Have you looked at what's happening in Wireshark or something similar, to see what the situation is at the network level?

Comment: Do you know which part of the code is taking the time?

Comment: sr.ReadToEnd(); takes 350 ms and so does req.GetResponse()

Comment: For me (I live in the netherlands) I get a "302 Moved" response to google.nl - if you also get a redirect, does the C++ example follow the new url?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` or `req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue` to **false**.

The basic gist is, that the request initially only sends the headers and waits for the server to respond with code 100 (continue). This is capped at 350ms. After the response is received the body of the request is sent. This way you don't put a very huge request on the wire (with a body of many MB), when the server will deny the request anyway (redirect or authentication required, or something wrong in the headers, etc).

This [link](http://basildoncoder.com/blog/turbocharging-net-webservice-clients.html) has a very detailed explanation.